# How to merge relation, node and way properly together in overpass-turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm using overpass-turbo to extract information like schools, kindergartens etc. I first just extracted nodes - but then found out it is not giving me all information I want (schools/kindergartens are missing). 
I figured, that there are ways, relations and nodes etc. and created this overpass query:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
( node["amenity"="school"];
  way["amenity"="school"];
  relation["amenity"="school"]; );
out center;
```

The problem is now, that many schools are duplicated (sometimes as node / relation or way). Since I want to import it in my own database I want to have this properly deduplicated. How to do this? :) What is a good way to merge ways / nodes / relations together?

Comment: hi there - many thanks for steppin up the plate with this awesome question: 
with "nwr" you get a merged results merged out of nodes ways and rels in one step. cf: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL